# retrieve json array from php json decode

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

i have a javascript to create json array and it has a ajax post method, i have to know how this json array should decode in the php side?

My javascript function:

```
var invoices = {invoice: [{ "customerName" : "John" ,"reciptionName" : "Doe" ,"datee" : "2017-09-09" ,"total" : tot }], invoiceLine: []};

    for(i=1; i<=count+arr.length-1; i++){

        var ss = String(i);
        if(arr.includes(ss)){
            continue;
        }
        invoices.invoiceLine.push({

            "itemName" : document.getElementById('item'+i).value ,
            "qty" : document.getElementById('inputQty'+i).value ,
            "value" : document.getElementById('value'+i).value
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveInvoice.php",
    data: {json : JSON.stringify(invoices)},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    location.reload();
    }
    });
```

and this is my php:(it will not save data to the database. I want first invoice data to save in the database for now. Then i can use invoiveLine data to another table inserting.)

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    //$dbpass = "dbpassword";
    $dbname = "inventory";

    $jsonInvoice = json_decode($POST['invoices'],true);

    $customerName = $jsonInvoice.["invoice"][0].["customerName"];
    $reciptionName = $jsonInvoice.["invoice"][0].["reciptionName"];
    $date = $jsonInvoice.["invoice"][0].["datee"];
    $total = $jsonInvoice.["invoice"][0].["total"];



    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, '');

    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "insert into invoice (customerName,reciptionName,date,total) values ('$customerName','$reciptionName','$date',$total)";

    $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $insertId = mysql_insert_id();

    echo $insertId;
```

Comment: What does `$POST['invoices']` look like? Also, the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is outright [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL Injection :)

Comment: First of all, don't use mysql_query, use mysqli or PDO and paramaterize your query string so you're not subject to SQL injection.

Comment: i corrected $POST to $_POST but still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

`$customerName = $jsonInvoice["invoice"][0]["customerName"];`

I think that you are getting sintax errors, caused by dots.
json_decode returns an array, you have to access the attributes in the way that I wrote above. (see [this](http://php.net/json_decode) for further info)

Also, take care of the recommendations that other users gave you about mysqli